# Why was this fantastic question deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I asked a very popular question recently, that asked people to come up with code that you wouldn't expect to print an obscenity or insult.

It was great fun and it got a lot of creative answers.

Now it's been deleted.

Why would you do that??
To the mod who deleted it, I've got a lot of code I can send you to run...

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28279/shortest-simplest-code-that-prints-an-unexpected-obscenity

Comment: Please read [Shog9's answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1639/9275) on that question.

Comment: Your question was popular, for sure, but popularity does not make a post "fantastic" or otherwise a good fit for the site (and the linked post explains why it's a poor fit for the site). It reminds me of the early days of Stack Overflow, where there were posts like [programmer cartoons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/84556/13) or [boat-programming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14470/13) that were very popular but totally wrong for the site.